# linkbutton click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have dynamically added a linkbutton to the page. But the click event is not working. What could be the problem? Thanks for your help. I am adding a linkbutton on button click event.
Here is my code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton(); 
    lb.Text = "dsadsa";
    lb.ID = "22";
    lb.CommandArgument = "22"; 
    lb.CommandName = "22"; 
    lb.Command += new CommandEventHandler(lb1_Command); 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lb);
}
protected void lb1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = e.CommandName; 
}
```

Comment: You need to add a click event in the same manner that you've used to add your command event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the linkbutton isn't recreated when the linkbutton is clicked thus you're event handler isn't registered thus you're event doesn't get fired.

Adding a button in an eventhandler is almost always a bad idea, you can add this by default on the page and just set it to `Button.Visible = false`. This way you can register your eventhandler earlier in say `Page_Load` and set it visible from the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for adding the control on controls even handlers. The best way to add control is `Init` event, I guess on `Load` it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the control in the page load as the link button is not created again after it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

See both linkbutton click and linkbutton command in action: http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=p-yDA-ntG0K4UrMkiImuRQ